# Flutter: how to pass herotag through onRefresh callback

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following widget at my home page:

```
CardsCarouselWidget(restaurantsList: _con.topRestaurants, heroTag: 'my_restaurants'),
```

And, inside CardsCarouselWidget, I have the following builder, for each restaurant:

```
Container(
            height: 288,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: widget.restaurantsList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Details',
                        arguments: RouteArgument(
                          id: widget.restaurantsList.elementAt(index).id,
                          heroTag: widget.heroTag,
                        ));
                  },
                  child: CardWidget(restaurant: widget.restaurantsList.elementAt(index), heroTag: widget.heroTag),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
```

The problem is, when I am in the `/Details` Widget, and try to call the `onRefresh: _con.refreshRestaurant`, everything seems to work fine, but I am getting an error, due to one tag for a  Hero widget:

```
The following ArgumentError was thrown building DetailsWidget(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#3f564], MediaQuery], state: _DetailsWidgetState#be245):
Invalid argument(s)
The relevant error-causing widget was
    DetailsWidget 
lib\route_generator.dart:53
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _StringBase.+  (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:262:57)
#1      _DetailsWidgetState.build 
package:app/…/pages/details.dart:87
#2      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4619
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4502
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild
```

Here is where I believe the problem is, inside `/Details` (`_DetailsWidgetState`), where the `tag:` expects a `widget.routeArgument`, which does not happen at refresh:

```
SliverAppBar(
                          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.9),
                          expandedHeight: 300,
                          elevation: 0,
                          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                            collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
                            background: Hero(
                              tag: widget.routeArgument.heroTag + _con.restaurant.id,
                              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                imageUrl: _con.restaurant.image.url,
                                placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset(
                                  'assets/img/loading.gif',
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

And, at my controller (I use MVC):

```
  Future<void> refreshRestaurant() async {
    var _id = restaurant.id;
    restaurant = new Restaurant();
    reviews.clear();
    ureviews.clear();
    
    listenForRestaurant(id: _id, message: S.of(context).restaurant_refreshed_successfuly);
    listenForRestaurantReviews(id: _id);
    listenForUserRestaurantReviews(id: _id);
  }
```

As at my "refresh" callback I am not calling a new route, how could I solve this thing of the Hero Tag?

Comment: very unclear, what refresh are you referring

Comment: @neuromancer https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html